# Loading a .dll file in Windows Python 3.4

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, anaconda, ctypes

Currently, I am using Python 3.4 out of the Anaconda Suite. I have a file called "libPiCam.dll" within my working directory and I am trying to load it in this fashion:

```
from ctypes import cdll

def load(x):
    """Loads DLL library where argument is location of library"""
    x = cdll.LoadLibrary(x)
    return x

lib = load("PiCamLib")
```

But when doing that, I get this tracer back

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-27-8d86fac88101>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/User/Documents/Python Scripts/PicamCode/PixisTest.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/Documents/Python Scripts/PicamCode')

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/User/Documents/Python Scripts/PicamCode/PixisTest.py", line 49, in <module>
    piFunction = load(piFunctionLib)

  File "C:/Users/User/Documents/Python Scripts/PicamCode/PixisTest.py", line 32, in load
    x = cdll.LoadLibrary(x)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 429, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 351, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

What confuses me the most is that I have a file called "PiCam.dll" and load it in this fashion:

```
picamLibrary = 'picam'
picam = cdll.LoadLibrary(picamLibrary)
```

And loads using th eLoad method above. This works without error. I tried shaping my call to load libPiCam to be the same way, but I get the same error. As background, I created and compiled the "libPiCam.dll" file from a C++ file in order to wrap it, allowing me to call C++ functions from Python (I followed [Calling C/C++ from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python)).

So, what do I do?

Comment: `.so` shared libraries are specific to unix. On windows you have to compile to a `dll`.

Comment: I already tried that, as I mentioned above

Comment: you may want to edit and update your question. The first part with the `.so` file makes no sense as I tried to point out in my previous comment.

Comment: Done. Still have any idea on how to fix this? I get the same traceback.

Comment: I think this can occur when the bitness of the dll and the bitness of python do not match.  E.g. 64bit python vs. 32bit library.

Comment: Get `depends.exe` from dependencywalker.com. This is a tool that allows you to analyze a DLL (or any Windows module) concerning its type, exports import etc. Opening the DLL there might give you a hint where to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I notice the naming isn't quite consistent: issue with `libPiCam.dll` vs `"PiCamLib"` doesn't work, while `PiCam.dll` vs `"picam"` does. Is it a an issue with case? Have you tried `"libpicam"`?

Otherwise, I wouldn't be surprised with it being an issue with the Anaconda distribution itself. I've had several issues that turned out to be bugs that occur when Anaconda interacts with windows. Ie. the c++ compiler not working properly, not being able to import pywin32 unless I run the .py script with IPython for some reason, etc.